# C# - how can i convert “text text 542050.0000 text text” to “text text 542050 text text”?

Tags: c#, regex, string

How can I convert the following string:

```
string x = "text text 542050.0000 text 245.00 text";
```

to this: "text text 542050 text 245 text"

i want to keep all text in this string , just remove decimal part of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve for the general case of removing decimals in strings, you can use RegEx:

```
var input = "text text 542050.0000 text text";
var regex = "((?<keep>[0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+)";
var matchEvaluator = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator((m) => m.Groups["keep"].Value);
var output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, regex, matchEvaluator);
```

The RegEx will match all decimals, and return the whole part as a replacement. Note that if you have a string like 5.2.1 then this will result in "5.1".

If you want to output a specific number of decimal places you could try this:

```
var input = "text text 542050.0129 text text";
var regex = "([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)";
var matchEvaluator = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator((m) => {
    var decimalValue = double.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value);
    return String.Format("{0:0.000}", Math.Round(decimalValue, 3));
});
var output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, regex, matchEvaluator);
```

In my example, I've rounded to 3 dp and formatted with 3 dp (formatting to ensure that it always outputs .000  - you can remove this step if you don't need it). For "542050.0129" above, it would output "542050.013"

Comment: Thank you for your correct answer,Can you control the number of decimal digits between zero and (n) by the same method?

Comment: Replace the second `+` by `{,5}` where `5` is the number of digits (in this case 5).